# Unable to use VersionControlServer.GetItem() or GetItems() on file which has been renamed?

Tags: tfs

I am attempting to use the VersionControlServer.GetItem() or GetItems() methods to retrieve an item from TFS version control which has been RENAMED. I found that the following approach works properly when an item has been DELETED. However, if the last change on an item is a "delete, source rename" then these API calls do not retrieve the item.

This approach works for a deleted item. But not a renamed item.
For a deleted item I get back what I expect... an item with a deletion ID. For a renamed item I get an exception.

Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlException: Item (serveritem) was not found in source control at version T.

```
VersionControlService.GetItem(ServerItem, VersionSpec.Latest, DeletedState.Any)
```

I attempted to work around this by using the GetItems method. And indeed I do not get an exception... however GetItems returns an empty itemset.

```
VersionControlService.GetItems(ServerItem, VersionSpec.Latest, RecursionType.None, DeletedState.Any, ItemType.Any);
```

It appears that this is a bug or something in the API. It's as if the API doesn't treat renamed files as though they ever existed. This is further supported by my experiments using VersionControlService.ServerItemExists()

For a DELETED item this will return TRUE.
For a RENAMED item this will return FALSE

```
VersionControlService.ServerItemExists(ServerItem, VersionSpec.Latest, DeletedState.Any, ItemType.Any);
```

So, is there any way to get an item which has been renamed if you only know the ServerItem path?  I am using TFS 2010, BTW.

Comment: Are you querying on the *old* name or the *new* name?  You need to query on the old name *at the version it existed*, not the tip.

Comment: Old name, I can try specifying a different versionspec

Comment: As lame as I think this is... it worked, I am now able to properly handle renames in the application I am working on. Thanks! TFS seems to have a real personality disorder in the way that it handles rename operations... yes it's a "delete" but it's a special "delete" which causes the item to not exist at other changeset versions. Very confusing

Answer (score 0):

You can use VersionControl.QueryHistory(new ItemSpec(path, RecursionType.None)).Count() > 0 to check if a path existed at any point in time in your collection.
It doesn't care about renames, deletes, etc...